# tokumx1.2.1 update slow,why?

Tags: performance, tokumx

we have a java application ,use tokumx1.2.1。we use mongo-java-client-2.10.1 for write and read.Write about 5 times per second，but sometime it use time exceed 10s.the dba monitor tokumx times not exceed 10ms,can anyone help me? thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you are measuring two different times: the elapsed time (from your application point of view this is >10s) versus the execution time (the query runs in <10ms?). The elapsed time can be affected by factors such as network latency and queueing on the DB  server. I would try profiling your application code to get more information on where the time is spent, and look at DB server performance metrics such as the queue length, I/O, and page faults to see if there are any correlated factors for the slow queries.

Comment: First of all, you should upgrade to tokumx 1.3.3 to pick up some bugfixes.  It will help if you can provide some more information: please describe your schema, and the types of operations you're performing (specific queries are important).  Also, please check the log for slow query reports and if you see any, add them to your question here so we can analyze them.  Stennie is right, it may be the case that the queries run quickly on the server but you have network latency problems or issues in your Java timing code.  Any code snippets you can show will help too.

Comment: we try another application server，it uses time ok.the network latency is major factor,thank you!